# Goto window issue in IntelliJ CE

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I am on IntelliJ CE 20231.1. When I open the Goto popup (the screenshot of the window is attached to show which popup I am talking about), after I type the filename, the arrow keys do not work to navigate on the shown suggestions, neither does enter work to select the file, nor escape works to close the window. All the operations work fine with mouse.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please try to [disable all third-party plugins](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html) and restart the IDE. If the problem remains contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and share the IDE logs. (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data)